# Programmatically controlled virtual drive

Tags: macos, windows-xp, nt

How would I go about creating a virtual drive with which I can programmatically and dynamically change the contents?

For instance, program A starts running and creates a virtual drive.  When program B looks in the drive, it sees an error log and starts reading/processing it.  In the middle of all this program A gets a signal from somewhere and decides to add to the log. I want program B to be unaware of the change and just keep on going.  Program B should continue reading as if nothing happened.  Program A would just report a rediculously large file size for the log and then fill it in as appropriate.  Program A would fill the log with  tags if program B tries to read past the last entry.

I know this is a weird request but there's really no other way to do this... I basically can't rewrite program B so I need to fool it.

How do I do this in windows?  How about OSX?

Comment: Instead of asking how you can do this the way you think it should work, just tell everyone what the issue is and see if people can suggest a workable solution.

Comment: The question is very broad.  We need more specifics.

Answer (score 1):

Found your question poorly worded. For the first question I would recommend using disk images, but those are Mac only. I have no experience with it but [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net) might work because it should be cross platform. For the second question I really don't know it is possible.